# Reverse RecyclerView items in Chat application(First item at bottom)

Tags: android-recyclerview

I want to implement a chat application what i want is when i send a message it should show at the last...., just like chat application.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"/>
```

javaclass.xml

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in your java class.

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: I will add a note:
- `isSmoothScrollbarEnabled` is not recommended if your recycler elements have different heights (which is usually the case in a chat app)
- `setReverseLayout` is only useful if your list is ordered such as it starts with newest messages